# Select a element only if is not a sibling (immediately or not) of another

Tags: css-selectors

Lets have this:

```html
<blockquote>
  <header>header</header>
  <p>no</p>
  <p>no</p>
  <p>no</p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <p>yes</p>
  <p>yes</p>
  <p>yes</p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <p>no</p>
  <header>header</header>
  <p>no</p>
  <p>no</p>
</blockquote>
```

I am searching for a CSS selector (without altering the HTML) that target all the `p` that are both inside a `blockquote` but without a `header` sibling (those with the word “yes”).

I have tried with: `blockquote :not(header) ~ p`, `blockquote > p ~ :not(header)`, and similar others with no avail. Is this even possible with CSS only?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible in pure css. The first two cases could be covered by overwriting your rules in a sibling selector, eg

```css
blockquote p {
  background-color: hotpink;
}
blockquote header ~ p {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

However in the third case while you can ***match*** elements based on their prior siblings you cannot ***select*** elements based on their prior siblings.

[Is there a "previous sibling" selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)

You also cannot select a parent of an element which would allow you to select the children of the parent of a `header` element.

[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Your `:not` selectors are matching the following:

`blockquote :not(header) ~ p` = any p with at least one previous sibling that is not a `header`
`blockquote > p ~ :not(header)` = any element that's not a `header` element with at least one previous `p` sibling